# How to generate index of occurrence in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling finding the correct formula to fulfil this table.

[image]

Could you give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
="STUFF_"&A2&"_"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(α,"STUFF_"&α&"_"&COUNTIF(A$2:α,α)))
```

---

Or, make it dynamic so whenever there is a new entry it will give the desired output in the adjacent cells hence no need to change the ranges,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")), 
     MAP(A2:INDEX(A:A,α),LAMBDA(φ,"STUFF_"&φ&"_"&COUNTIF(A$2:φ,φ))))
```

---